# Sync invocation to a Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

Need to create a script to invoke a Lambda (basically the 'invoke' api of the  Lambda) in **Synchronous** manner.

Questions:

1. Where can this script can be deployed to invoke the Lambda? Execution time of script will be past 1 hour, so we can't deploy this script in a Lambda, since Lambda times out in 15 min.  Other possible way to deploy: EC2, Step function, etc.
2. Since it is a sync invocation, can Lambda throw a success & failed response back to the invoker/caller in case of successful execution & failed to execute respectively? How can those response be catched? Based on the success & failed response, there are some decisions to make.
3. Can retry be configured for this invoker/caller, not the Lambda?
4. To call the Lambda, the invoker/caller should have the relevant permission. Can this be configured in the invoker/caller or in EC2/step function?

[Optional Read] The script will have the following logic:

1. Iterate over dates (for example: from 10th july to 12th dec)
2. For each day, say currentDate, call the Lambda with input as currentDate. (Lambda will fetch a file from S3 for currentDate. do some processing for currentDate and delete currentDate from S3.)
3. if Lambda successfully processed the file for currentDate, insert currentDate in a SuccessList
4. if Lambda failed to process the file for currentDate, insert currentDate in a FailedList.

Comment: Sounds like a viable Step Functions workflow.

Comment: Yes, I went ahead with Step function, it seems fruitful so far.